# LongListSelector in a panorama causes "empty" elements when navigating back

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a problem with the LongListSelector in a Windows Phone 7 application. I have a list of people in a LongListSelector (databound to a ViewModel) and when I select on of the items, navigate to another page, and then navigates back again, the LongListSelector appears to have none of the bindings refreshed. All the items are visible in the list but they appear to be completely empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought is the use of a LongListSelector in a Panorama isn't a good idea and is not the sort of thing that a Panorama was intended to contain. That said, without seeing how your bindings are set up or what you're doing which should update them its going to be very hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting a possible bug in the LongListSelector.
Check out the link below:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/8222